# Calculating percentage of two hold in two different shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have two big datasets of different species. One shp is point which shows the location of species, and the other file is in polygon of same places and has got attribute table of public and free holds. I wanted to see how many percentage of the first one (point shp) is in free hold and how many is in public hold?

Comment: Perform a spatial join to get your polygon attributes onto the points then summary statistics to count with case field of public/freehold field.. percentage is count of points in each class divided by the sum of all classes (multiplied by 100 for visualization perhaps). How can you tell if land is public or freehold in your polygons? What attributes do you have in your table?

Comment: In my second file in name of T, I have on part which shows public hold and free dold. I want to see percentage of overlaid layer of File one by name of F on file two(T).